# Apollo graphql query with parameters

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I am following along with this Graphql intro https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/getting-started/. I've got my files set up (slightly modified), and the base query is working on http://localhost:4000/.

My next question after getting through the basics was, how do I get data based on parameters? I've gotten this far, but the query in playground doesn't return results.

**index.js**

```
const typeDefs = gql`
    type Item {
        name: String
        description: String
        full_url: String
        term: String
    }

    type Query {
        items: [Item]
        itemsSearch(term: String!): [Item]
    }
`;

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        // this works. it is the example from the guide.
        items: () => items,
        // this doesn't work. `term` is always undefined
        itemsSearch: term => {
            console.log('term', term);
            console.log('items', items);
            return items.filter(item => item.title.indexOf(term) > -1 || item.author.indexOf(term) > -1);
        },
    },
};
```

Then I'm running this query in playground. (mostly working from https://graphql.org/graphql-js/passing-arguments/)

```
{
  itemsSearch(term: "Rowling") {
    title
    author
  }
}
```

I get a successful response but no data. As mentioned, logging `term` in the itemsSearch resolver prints undefined.

Any idea how I can pass that param `term` to the resolver and get results? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please try `itemsSearch: (parent, { term }) => {`?

Comment: @pzaenger Yes! I have `term` now. Thank you. Add as an answer, if you'd like me to accept it.

Comment: this was detaily described in "next steps" of the same tutorial, basic knowledge

Comment: if you want to use variables, don't ask ... https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [arguments of a resolver](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/#resolver-arguments) are `parent`, `args`, `context` and `info`:

> `args`
>
> An object that contains all GraphQL arguments provided for this field.
>
> For example, when executing `query{ user(id: "4") }`, the `args`
> object passed to the user resolver is `{ "id": "4" }`.

Therefore you get `term` through `args` with:

```
itemsSearch: (parent, { term }) => {
   ...
}
```

Or:

```
itemsSearch: (parent, args) => {
   const term = args.term;
   ...
}
```